# C# - What do the auto generated constructors from the exception class do in visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, exception

So in a few days I have a test coming up where I have to program a project in 2 days, afterwards my assessors will get the chance to ask me questions about what I made. One of the things I need to include in my program is Exceptions, I created a custom exception and let the constructors be automatically generated (see below) but I only use the second one. Now I could just delete the bottom two but I think it'll be more handy to try to understand what they are actually used for.

```
 public class CantConnectToDatabaseException : Exception
{
    public CantConnectToDatabaseException()
    {
    }

    public CantConnectToDatabaseException(string message) : base(message)
    {
    }

    public CantConnectToDatabaseException(string message, Exception innerException) : base(message, innerException)
    {
    }

    protected CantConnectToDatabaseException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) : base(info, context)
    {
    }
}
```

If someone could explain this to me in a way I can remember and explain it back to someone I would greatly appreciate that, I tried reading up on it through MSDN but I couldn't follow it.

Comment: Have a look at the code. What does it look like they do? Do you have any specific questions? Is there something about it that's unclear, or seems counterintuitive? As with any problem in programming, when you see a wall of unintelligible barf, break it down into smaller and smaller units until they turn manageable. And read MSDN.

Comment: I've never used that last constructor, but having a constructor with an `innerException` property is very standard for exceptions.  It's common to "wrap" exceptions in parent exceptions as they bubble up the stack.

Comment: They just call the base `Exception` class with the passed parameters. Other than that, they don't do anything unless you add some code.

Comment: I use exceptions alot and I always automatically generate them but the last two constuctors always go unused, I tried figuring out what they are used for but I can't find a clear explination.

Comment: If you're wondering what the base class does, the code is public: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/exception.cs,f092fb2b893a0162

Comment: I'm not your instructor, but unless your doing something special when that exception happens I would question why you needed to add an exception for that specified purpose.

Comment: @Steve our instructors encourage us to make custom exceptions to see if we understand the concept of them

Comment: @Tom I figured that was the case, happy coding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`InnerException` is used when you catch an exception and rethrow it.

For a somewhat contrived example, say you have a bunch of data access methods. All kinds of things can go wrong in them, so you wrap them like so:

```
try
{
    //  stuff
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw new MyDataAccessException("Error accessing data", ex);
}
```

Now your code can catch `MyDataAccessException` to get any exception caused by data access problems, but the handler can look at the `InnerException` property of the `MyDataAccessException` object to find out exactly what went wrong, and where.

```
protected CantConnectToDatabaseException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) : base(info, context)
```

> [This constructor is called during deserialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tz6bzkbf(v=vs.110).aspx) to reconstitute the exception object transmitted over a stream. For more information, see [XML and SOAP Serialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/90c86ass(v=vs.110).aspx).

Serialization is when you take an object in memory and convert it into some kind of text or binary representation that can be transmitted over a network or stored on a disk. [SOAP, "Simple Object Access Protocol"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP), is a protocol you use to talk to web services.

So that constructor would be used when a webservice throws an exception and the system has to get the exception over the network to the client.

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for. I hate having code in my program I don't understand. I doubt they'll ask about it but if they do I'll atleast be prepared!

Answer (score 0):

Just check the documentation on MSDN for the constructors you're calling with `base()`, such as [Exception Constructor (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/48ca3hhw(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Initializes a new instance of the Exception class with a specified error message.

Or [Exception Constructor (String, Exception)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/804f22sf(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Initializes a new instance of the Exception class with a specified error message and a reference to the inner exception that is the cause of this exception.

They're used to populate the exception-to-be-thrown with relevant information about the exception and its surroundings.

If you hate your fellow programmers, you only use the parameterless one.

Comment: @Steve and I'm not the OP.

Comment: I understand how constructors work but I don't undertand the parameters that are given with the last 2, I don't get in wich case you would use them. I tried looking at MSDN but it's very technical, I'm only a first year student so alot of the terms are unfamiliar for me.